# Useful steam from Baromatic Vortex Upgrade?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

When using the "Baromatic Vortex Upgrade" skill of the rogue scientist, you get a buff of heat exhaust and are surrounded by steam for several turns as you move around.

[image: steam, no not that Steam]

Is there a beneficial use of this steam?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular class, but I'd bet that the steam does damage to nearby enemies.

Answer (score 1):

According to [dredmorpedia](http://j-factor.com/dredmorpedia/), that is caused by the "heat exhaust" debuff you get after firing the upgraded cannon. The debuff itself is a minor mana drain; the clouds of steam that surround you are named "harmless steam cloud" and have no effect other than looking pretty.